# Json.net Deserialize to JObject derived type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

```
public class A : JObject
{}
```

and I have the folowing deserialization code

```
using (StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(responseStreamReader))
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<A>(reader);
    }
}
```

But it throws Invalid Cast Exception

in fact the deserializer just need to create new A() instead of new JObject() and do exactly the same after that, it would be enough for me.

How can I deserialize to a more specific JObject type ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you inheriting `JObject`? And why do you expect `JsonReader` to be castable to a type `A`?

Comment: I have a lot of code that manipulate JObject or JToken so inheriting from it will directly enable this code and that would be nice.

I would like to add some functionalities to it. I can use extensions methods and compositing, but inheriting would give me all at once.

Comment: the JsonReader would deserialize to JObject so it should not be a problem to deserialize it to A that is a JObject too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to deserialize directly to your JObject-derived `A` class because the internals of Json.Net handle JTokens specially.  However, you can easily work around the problem with two small changes to your code.

1. Add a constructor to your `A` class which accepts a `JObject` and passes the same to the base class constructor.

   ```
   public class A : JObject
   {
       public A(JObject jo) : base(jo)
       {
       }

       public A() : base()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your deserialization method, deserialize to a JObject, then construct your `A` class from that.

   ```
   using (StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
       using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(responseStreamReader))
       {
           JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
           return new A(serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader));
       }
   }
   ```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S8d3S6

Comment: Thx I think it's the simplest and best solution. However the extra copy bothers me. 
Changing one line in https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs in Load at 386 from JObject o = new JObject(); to T o = new T(); would do it but I don't feel like changing and maintenaning this change :).

I think I will go for classical compositing approch instead